# source_file.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'RegisterServerEvent')

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto

Code:

```
RegisterServerEvent("bms:services:getlicenses")
AddEventHandler("bms:services:getlicenses", function()
  local src = source 
  TriggerClientEvent("bms:services:getlicenses", src, licenses)
end)
```

Error:

source_file.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'RegisterServerEvent')

Comment: `RegisterServerEvent` is not defined. You probably have to load something…

Comment: what would be the best course of action to define this.

Answer (score 0):

`RegisterServerEvent` is wrong.

Use `RegisterNetEvent`. All event handlers will register as server/client automatically.